# Casting 2 separate methods in a Subclass

Tags: java, casting

So I basically have 2 methods I want to run, but I want one JButton I've made to do them both.

I basically have a GUI. I have a Mobile, MP3 and Gadget Class. The one I have trouble is a Shop for the Gadget, where the GUI is made. They contain buttons.

I want to run a method to make a call, but I'm not sure how to. I keep getting a Cast error. I also have to insert '0' in the line, as my method requires an int. Is there a way to allow it to take the duration from my GUI text box called 'Duration'?

So my code for the Shop is here:

```
 public void makeCall() 

{
    int index = 0;
    Gadget Gadgets = GadgetList.get(index);
    if (index!= -1)
{
    Mobile mobile = (Mobile) GadgetList.get(index);
    mobile.makePhoneCall();  
    mobile.insertDuration(0);
}
else if(Gadgets instanceof Mobile)
{
    Mobile mobile = (Mobile) Gadgets;
}
else
{
    System.out.println("This not a mobile phone");
}

}
```

My Mobile Phone class has this method I want to run:

```
public void makePhoneCall()
{
    if(credit == 0)
    System.out.println("Insert more than 0 credit to make a phone call!");
else {
    if(credit >= duration) {
    System.out.println("The phone number " + number + " has been dialed and is being called for " + duration + " minutes");
    credit = credit - duration;
    duration = 0;
}
else {
    if(credit < duration)
    System.out.println("You do not have enough credit to make a phone call! Your credit is " + credit + " pounds");
}
```

Help with this will allow me to understand the concept of the rest of the work! Many thanks to any help I get.

Comment: What's the specific error you get, and where specifically does it occur?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: You should stick to the Java Naming Convention: variable names must *not* start with an uppercase letter, except for constants; conditional and repeat statements like `if` or `while` should use braces.

Comment: @Makoto I don't actually get an error now. But I just want to know how to actually use 2 methods in one button. I want to run 2 methods from my Mobile class, and I want to get text from a JTextField in the GUI.